# Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated

Tags: php

i have a deprecated function in my plugin code :

```
static function vksort(&$arr, $valuekey) {
    $valuekey = sustr::preg_filter('A-Za-z0-9 ', $valuekey);
    uasort($arr, create_function('$a,$b', 'return strcasecmp($a["'.$valuekey.'"], $b["'.$valuekey.'"]);'));
}
```

how i can change the create_function to function.

Comment: 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic on this stack, you should ask the Ultimate SEO plugin support

Answer (score 2):

Your server runs with a PHP version that doesn't support create_function.

From the PHP manual about [create function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

> Warning This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED
> as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.
>
> If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native anonymous function should
> be used instead.

If the plugin is yours I would suggest just that, replace the create_function with anonymous function.

If the plugin is not yours and its a paid plugin, contact the plugin author and alert him of the error, ask him to give you the updated version.

If the plugin is free, you can update the code manually (If you know how), but that can be problematic. When the plugin will be updated your changes will be removed.
If this is the only option, make sure to save the plugin with the changes somewhere safe so if the plugin will be updated you will have the previous plugin version with your fix for quick re-apply.

***EDIT***

Same code but with anonymous function

```
static function vksort(&$arr, $valuekey) {
    $valuekey = sustr::preg_filter('A-Za-z0-9 ', $valuekey);
    uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) use($valuekey) {
        return strcasecmp($a[$valuekey], $b[$valuekey]);
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't know how to change the function from create_function to function(), do u know any how ? its a free plugin called SEO Ultimate

Comment: @ZiadElKhomssi the answer  was edited to contain a copy paste solution, however,  3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here, you should have asked  this question to SEO Ultimate support

Comment: thank u the edit worked